# Is there anything similar to DirectoryInfo for registry paths? (Same functions and attributes)

Tags: c#, path, registry, directoryinfo

Due to the fact that I'm using the `DirectoryInfo` class for almost every directory path I have, I also decided to use it in order to handle some registry paths. I mean, a registry path is nothing other but a directory path because both are divided into folders referenced by backslashes.

So, if I pass the string `@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\Scsi Port 0"` to a new instance `dir` of type `DirectoryInfo` and print out `dir.Root`my output is `D:\`. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.root?view=net-7.0) link, my output should be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Or am I wrong by asserting that I can handle a registry path like a directory path?

If it doesn't work with registry paths - is there anything similar to DirectoryInfo for registry paths? Best would be if it's contained in the NETCore App 1.1 framework which is my target framework!

EDIT: Okay, I experimented a bit and it seems like `DirectoryInfo` needs a drive letter at the beginning of every path or else it will search for this directory in the applcation folder. The `DirectoryInfo.Root` then returns the correct string. So the question now is: Is there anything similar to DirectoryInfo for registry paths?

Comment: Can't use `DirectoryInfo`. Maybe what you are looking for is `RegistryKey` class or `Registry` static class

Comment: Just realized you said .Net core. There probably aren't any registry related classes in .Net core since it's meant to run on any platform and non-windows environments won't have a windows style registry.

Comment: I searched the net a bit and unfortunately there aren't any registry related classes in .Net Core... I used `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` before but it's not contained in the .Net Core framework... However, I solved my problem by using Strings and splitting them with `String.Split()`. But nevertheless thanks for your advice!